# Uploading large tiff files in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, ng2-file-upload

I am developing a web app using MEAN Stack and Angular 6. I want to upload tiff files(maps) with large file size.(max size is around 1.4 GB).I used  'ng2fileUpload' and 'multer' for that but it does not allow to store large files. Is there any good method to use for uploading large files in nodejs. My preavious post is on this link.  '[Uploading files using multer gives 'request entity too large' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53088627/uploading-files-using-multer-gives-request-entity-too-large-error)'

Comment: Can you  provide code examples?

Comment: Can you post directly to an object store like [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and skip the Node part?

Comment: @Wezel I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should check first if there is a limit on max upload on the server site instead of the client side. There is a limit with apache service.